# Backup and Archive Strategy Question

Tags: backup

I am having trouble finding a backup strategy for our code assets that 'just works' without any manual intervention.

Goal is to have an off-site backup (a synchronized one) so that when we check-in files, create builds, etc. to the network drive, the entire folder structure is automatically synchronized and backed-up (in real time, or 1x per day) at some off-site location so if our office blows up, we don't lose all of our data.

I have looked into some online backup services, but have not yet had any success. Some are quirky/buggy, others limit file size and/or kinds of files (which doesn't work well for developer files).

Everything gets checked in and saved to a single server (on a Raid Mirror), so we just need to have a folder on that server backed up/synchronized to some off-site location.

So my question is this. What are you using for your off-site backup strategy. What software, system, or service? Is there a be-all/end-all system of backing up your code assets that I just haven't found yet?

Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful if you listed more details such as what OS your server is, what versioning system you're using if anything, what types and sizes of files you have, etc.

Answer (score 1):

regarding software - use whatever suits you. [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) is my favorite nowadays - orchestrated with [backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/projects/show/backupninja/) under linux and some shadow-copy bat scripts under windows.
but really anything that can take snapshot of your data should be fine.

just make sure you:

1. send it another quickly accessible location regularly
2. store it offline [ get 2 usb drives, encrypt them with truecrypt, rotate them weekly and keep one at home ].
3. monitor whole procedure [ eg run recovery drill every 3 months, check automatically backup consistency and arrival time ]

Answer (score 0):

I use two Linux machines. One as local SVN server, which peridically exports and creates a tar dump of the repository and another at a remote location which updates its copy of the tar file via rsync. If you don't have the need for a colocate, you could rent a slicehost (http://www.slicehost.com)

Answer (score 0):

How about just rent some ftp space somewhere and have a script that zips and copies everything up once a night? Doesn't need to be complicated.